# Term for documentation/code/config

Tags: terminology, programming, software

I am looking for a term that would succinctly combine "documentation", "code", "config", essentially "intellectual property", or IP, but IP sounds somewhat formal/legaleze to me, I'm wondering if there is a less formal term. The context is, I am writing a document that describes how our software IP should be organized in repositories (which includes code, documentation, configuration, images, diagrams, etc).

Comment: howsabout "assets"?

Comment: PS: "IP" is very widely understood.

Comment: Yes assets isn't bad, the only reason I hesitate with it is because we do some web development work, and assets could be considered static assets in regards to web development (js, css, etc).  Still though, it may end up being what we go with.

Comment: yeah. personally i'd go for "web assets" and "corporate assets", or similar.

Comment: How about "stuff"?

Comment: Go with mobileink's 'assets.'

People pay large sums of money for software which manages… uh… stuff like that, and such apps often call such things 'assets.'

Quite apart from which if you're going into that much detail, isn't the context you describe exactly where you'd expect to find 'formal' terms? Try going anywhere near informality in there and watch it spiral into a problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Files** (or **version controlled files**), could be used as a simple general term for documents, code, etc. stored in your repositories. This is the term used in the main [SCM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) systems' documentation.  Files can be text or binary format.

Quoting [git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) :

> git-add - Add **file** contents to the index

and quoting [svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.intro.whatis.html) :

> Subversion manages **files and directories**, and the changes made to them, over time.

Answer (score 2):

Consider calling them *software artifacts*.

> An artifact is one of many kinds of tangible by-products produced during the development of software. Some artifacts (e.g., use cases, class diagrams, and other Unified Modeling Language (UML) models, requirements and design documents) help describe the function, architecture, and design of software. Other artifacts are concerned with the process of development itself—such as project plans, business cases, and risk assessments.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(software_development))

The article continues on to include *code* as an artifact.

Answer (score 1):

**Project records** can encompass all of those categories of tangible work product or intellectual property. If you think that is too broad or subject to interpretation, you could call them **essential records**. Identifying those items as records (to be kept and maintained in a repository) attaches a sense of their importance for future reference.

Answer (score -1):

The term *deliverable* might fit, and is used quite often within our consultancy firm.

> **Deliverable** is a term used in project management to describe a tangible or intangible product or service produced as a result of the project that is intended to be delivered to a customer (either internal or external). A deliverable could be a report, a document, a software product, a server upgrade or any other building block of an overall project.

(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deliverable))

Comment: I think deliverables implies output at the end of a release - e.g. external docs or built binary files. The repository may also contain lots of files that are not  'delivered' - in many cases source-code will not be delivered, and likewise internal documentation.

Comment: I don't hate it, but I agree with @k1eran, I would think deliverables would be talking about client deliverables in software, specifically providing features/functionality.